# Difference between row major and column major in data structure

Tags: data-structures

how to calculate row major and column major implementation in data structure using C. I want to know proper example wise, not the program code.

Comment: You've asked this question at a wrong site; you should instead switch to tutorials, or other community sites like Quora!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **row major**  elements are traversed row by row whereas in **column major**  elements are traversed column by column.

for example and details check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order

Mathematical expression for above is:- 
Lets consider an int array of size m*n and size-of-int s byte.
**Case 1:** if array indices starts with **0**
         In **RMO** (Row Major Order) to access an element `a[i][j]`, we are supposed to cross `i` rows each with elements equal to number of columns and `j` columns. So, `&a[i][j]=(i∗n+j)∗s+base` And similarly `&a[i][j]=(j∗m+i)∗s+base` when array is stored in **CMO** (Column major order).

**Case 2:** if array indices start with **1**
**RMO :** `&a[i][j]=((i−1)∗n+j−1)∗s+base`

**CMO :** `&a[i][j]=((j−1)∗m+i−1)∗s+base`

Comment: I want mathematical calculation.. for example there is a matrix of a[5][5] and calculations, if given base address is 502 for the row major and column major value with the element at a[2][4]

Comment: @Nisha I've provided the mathematical expression, hope you can calculate now.